# How to return the highest sum of a dataset according to a set date range?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, sum, sumifs

I have a column with different dates and another column with a series of expenses associated to the dates. I can have several expenses on the same date. I want it to return the date on which there has been the highest sum of expenses of the whole range of dates as well as the sum of these expenses, i.e. I want to know on which date there was the highest expense of the whole series but without including 01/07/2022 when making the calculations. So far I have managed to apply a formula that returns in E2 the day with the highest expenses (in this case  03/07/2022) but I cannot get the sum of the expenses for 03/07/2022 in E3.

```
=INDEX($A$8:$A$11;MATCH(MAX(SUMIF($B$8:$B$11;$B$8:$B$11));SUMIF($B$8:$B$11;$B$8:$B$11);0))
```

[image: see the picture attached]

Comment: I would use pivot table (there is a both an UI version and a programmatic formula version) and find max. Certainly there are other approach that can be put into a single cell. It's not worth the time unless you have a requirement to avoid helper columns.

Comment: Aside, a live example sheet > embedded image > hyperlink. See [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and ctrl+f "image" for embedding image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in E3:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(B:B; A:A=E2))
```

Comment: I've been using Excel for years, but I've never seen `FILTER`. That's a game changer. It's good that Google Sheets did a bit of R & D (rip-off and duplicate) from Microsoft. Thank you.