# Small detail when using this function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

Small detail when using =INDEX($A$8:$A$11;MATCH(MAX(SUMIF($B$8:$B$11;$B$8:$B$11));SUMIF($B$8:$B$11;$B$8:$B$11);0))) If the values in column B are all different it returns the correct date value, but if two identical values in column B coincide in different dates then it returns the date of the first value; it does not return the correct date and it keeps the first one that has the repeated value.
Any idea?

[image]

p.s This question can be added to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902131/how-to-return-the-highest-sum-of-a-dataset-according-to-a-set-date-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even more easier way:
On E2 Try this `=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(QUERY(A1:B," select A, sum(B) group by A Order By sum(B) Desc "),2))`
and format the date and currency accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily and differently to get:

1 - Make a helper table to get unique dates, You can use two ways

a) - Use `SUMIF` Function to get the sum of Expenditure in each unique date Like so `=IF(D2="",,SUMIF($A$2:$A,D2,$B$2:$B))` and drag it down.

b) - By using `QUERY` Function `=QUERY(A1:B11," select A, sum(B) group by A Order By sum(B) Desc ")`

2 - to get SUM BY DATE OF HIGHEST EXPENDITURE: `=MAX(E2:E)`

3 - to get DATE BY HIGHEST EXPENDITURE: `=INDEX($D$2:$D,MATCH($H$3,$E$2:$E,0),1)`

Make a copy of [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kG002yObFt00KbFyAnvP1g8JTuE4QKIiBYELxpSHFoQ/edit?usp=sharing) "make it yours."
Hope that answerd your question.